# Windows c++ libraries: What does the suffix 'z', 'd' and 'zd' mean?

Tags: c++, windows, lib, suffix

I am sure this has been asked somewhere before - but I can't make a google question how to find the information.

I have some windows c++ libraries (from a third-party) with the following extensions:

- ...core.lib (~ 800KB)
- ...cored.lib (~ 850KB)
- ...corez.lib (~ 21MB)
- ...corezd.lib (~ 29MB)

I thought that the 'd' stands for debug - as in it contains all the symbols required for debuggers to identify variable and function names. But I am not sure what the 'z' is about.... this adds huge amounts of data to the library file. What are the two suffixes and (if its not obvious) what is the difference (i.e. why / when would you use them)?

I think I must have had a "too-simplistic-view" of it before...

Comment: I *think* a `z` signals the inclusion of pdb-style debugging data.

Comment: @Bathsheba I got a hint that it might be statically linked libraries... because when I looked at the libraries for the same third party in Linux all the ones ending in `z` or `zd` where for `.a` libs and the other where for `.so` libs.... so z means statically linked? - maybe that is a windows thing because in Linux you can use the extension (a or so).

Comment: Yes, that seems more plausible than my idea. Thinking more about this, I've only ever seen separate pdb files: not ones that are embedded into actual libs. By the way, this is the kind of thing that the mighty @HansPassant knows about.

Comment: @Bathsheba ok, I'll roll with this idea for the moment :)  ... pdb was an interesting idea though, but as you say, they seem to be generated separately.

Comment: It's a bit naughty but you could ping @HansPassant via one of his answers. If he answers here, I'll be sure to upvote, and I'm sure you would too and accept.

Comment: @Bathsheba lol... I always assumed you could direct message someone - I never actually wanted to do that until just now ... I'll try your approach, if you never see me again.... you know why :o